# Generate CSS for Server Side Rendering in React - Material-UI

Tags: php, css, reactjs, symfony, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to generate CSS for Server Side Rendering according to  [Material UI - Server Rendering](https://material-ui.com/guides/server-rendering/)

I'm using React on Rails with PHP ([React Bundle](https://github.com/Limenius/ReactBundle)) is any other way to generate CSS? In docs we providing all whole content in one request in JS. In my case I must provide component to twig and next separately CSS. Any other ways?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can pass the CSS with the html template to client like, I did the same in one of my project.

```
const cssStyleTage = extractCSSFromMaterialUIServerSideAPI();
const componentStream = someHtmlConten;

const html = `
  <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      ${cssStyleTage}
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root">
            ${componentStream}
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>`;

// pass it to client, this you can open in any iframe at client side.
res.status(200).send(html);

// or otherwise just send the css styles separately.
res.status(200).send({
  cssStyleTags: cssStyleTage,
  html: componentStream
});
```

Am just giving an idea what are the possible ways this can be done, if that can help you to achieve your task.